# How to turn a number[] matches an interface with only numbers included

Tags: typescript, nestjs

i try to implement an incremental function for Planet Positions in my nestJS Backend.
My Planet look like this:

```
planets: Planet[] = [{
      name: 'A',
      [...]
      pos: this.generatePlanetPosition(),
      siege: false,
      [...]
    },
];
```

My Position Interface:

```
export interface PlanetPosition {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
```

and my function is this:

```
  generatePlanetPosition(): PlanetPosition {
  [...]
    let position = [this.x, this.y];
    return position;
  }
```

i get the error message, that the type number[] (of position) is missing the following properties from type 'PlanetPosition': x, y

how can i get to manage, that the function return both variables and fill the position in my Planet while matching the interface?

Comment: `let position = { x: this.x, y: this.y }`?

Comment: *"how can i get to manage, that the function return both variables and fill the position in my Planet while matching the interface?"* Can you explain a bit more what you mean by that?

Comment: I feel like more context would really help. What is `this` within `generatePlanetPosition`? Why are you returning an array when you've defined `PlanetPosition` as an object?

Comment: You're returning an array []. You should return an object {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface defines an object with `x` and `y` properties, but `[this.x, this.y]` creates an array with two elements; its type (assuming `x` and `y` are numbers) is `number[]`. `number[]` is not assignable to `{x: number; y: number}`. Arrays don't have `x` or `y` properties.

If you want a `PlanetPosition` from that function, return an object with `x` and `y` properties:

```typescript
generatePlanetPosition(): PlanetPosition {
    // ...
    let position = {x: this.x, y: this.y};
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^−−−−−−−−−^^−−−−−−−^
    return position;
}
```

...again assuming `this.x` and `this.y` are numbers.

Comment: this works like intended, thx :) Rest of the code not, but that was not my question here :D